# Run macro on variable data after filters

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Please help me with VBA code, I wanted to apply macro for uneven data. First I want to apply filter and in next blank column I wanna add information about filtered value. Also if filter criteria is nothing then it should proceed to next filter criteria and write my assigned statement to next column.i want to add each filter selection with remarks(which I wanna add in next column)in code itself.
I have tried recording macro but due to uneven data it's not working. For example if I've recorded macro for 200 entries and if it turns to 600 then data become wrong. I hope you are getting my query. Please help me with the code or procedure.

I have tried recording macro but it's not working as my data is variable. Every data shows different count of filter criteria but my macro runs for only on recorded cell i.e A1 to A1000

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that because this is no free code writing service it is necessary that you show either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made. Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you. Reading [ask] might help you to improve your question.

Comment: It's unclear what "uneven data" means here, so we can't really offer any suggestions.